# Inheriting @see documentation from the method being overridden?

Tags: java, javadoc

Given:

```
interface A
{
  /**
   * @see some other method
   */
  void isGreaterThan(int exclusiveMinimum);
}

interface B extends A
{
  /**
   * @see {@inheritDoc}
   * @throws IllegalArgumentException if [some condition]
   */
  @Override
  void isGreaterThan(int exclusiveMinimum);
}

interface C extends A
{
  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   * <p>
   * Records {@code IllegalArgumentException} if [some condition].
   * The list of recorded exceptions can be retrieved using {@link #getResult()}
   *
   * @see {@inheritDoc}
   */
  @Override
  void isGreaterThan(int exclusiveMinimum);
}
```

I would like `B.doSomething()` to inherit `@see` Javadoc tags from the method it is overriding but `{@inheritDoc}` doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

### What I'm trying to do

I've got two implementations of `A`. One throws an exception on the first failure. Another records multiple exceptions and allows them to retrieve the list of failures after all the validations has completed. Both sub-interfaces need to have the same methods, but only one of them will throw an exception. The other notes in its comment how to retrieve the list of exceptions.

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but it's generally better to omit doc comments on overridden methods, in which case they will inherit the javadoc from the interface automatically.

Comment: @MaksVerver Agreed. I tried this and it didn't help either.

Comment: I think you need to provide more details about what you are trying to do and what isn't working, exactly. If you use the standard javadoc tool then if you omit the doc comment on B.doSomething(), it will inherit the documentation from A.doSomething(), including the @see tag (I just checked).

Comment: @MaksVerver I've updated the question to explain what I'm trying to do.

Comment: The inherited documentation already includes the @see. You don’t need to specify it again. Unclear what you’re asking.

Comment: @user207421 that would be news ro me. I don't see the `@see` tag being inherited in IntelliJ's Javadoc viewer. Are you saying that the official Javadoc tool *does* inherit the tag?